# Improper controller structure not allowing multiple actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a basic app with 2 action buttons: one to add a positive score, one to add a negative score. However when I try to add a negative score, it adds the positive score instead. My code looks as follows.

Controller:

```
  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @record = Record.where(user_id: @user.id)
    @recordid = Record.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
  end

  def add_positive
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @recordid = Record.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
    @recordid.positivescore +=1
      if @recordid.save
        redirect_back(fallback_location: records_path)
     end
  end

  def add_negative
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @recordid = Record.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
    @recordid.negativescore +=1
      if @recordid.save
        redirect_back(fallback_location: records_path)
     end
  end
```

My view:

```
<%= @record.each do |user_record| %>
    Positive: <%= user_record.positivescore %> <%= button_to "Add Positive Score", :action => "add_positive" %>
    Negative: <%= user_record.negativescore %> <%= button_to "Add Negative Score", :action => "add_negative" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem I was facing -- whenever I tried to add a negative score, it would instead increase the positive score. After banging my head against the wall for a few hours, I found this was happening because of my routes.rb file.

Routes.rb:

```
  post '/profile/:id', to: 'users#add_positive'
  post '/profile/:id', to: 'users#add_negative'
```

This made me realize that I'm probably approaching the whole problem wrong and I shouldn't be defining 3 separate methods in my controller. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how I **should be** doing this?

Comment: You can just change your routes to `post '/profile/:id/add_positive', to: 'users#add_positive'` and the same for negative. Anyway, it seems the user has many records, but you get only one recordid (with find_by). This will update one random record from the user. You should pass the record_id

Comment: So I guess I was on the right track. Thanks a lot @Pablo, that worked! Want to leave an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep both methods, but they must have different routes:

```
post '/profile/:id/add_positive', to: 'users#add_positive'
post '/profile/:id/add_negative', to: 'users#add_negative'
```